# "Load xml" is filling null values in mysql

Tags: mysql, xml

I am running load xml command to fill values from an xml file to mysql table, but it is always filling null values.

I am running following command:

mysql> load xml local infile  'E:\Badges.xml' into table meta rows identified by  '`<row>`'

following are the content of my file:

```
<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:26:49.550" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:26:49.580" />
  <row Id="3" UserId="6" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row Id="4" UserId="15" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row Id="5" UserId="18" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row Id="6" UserId="21" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row Id="7" UserId="27" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.213" />
  <row Id="8" UserId="7" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-25T19:51:49.327" />
 </badges>
```

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution?

Thanks! in advance
Sangeeta

Answer (score 0):

The following file `badges.xml` works for me (care case sensitive):

```
<badges>
  <row id="1" userid="2" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:26:49.550" />
  <row id="2" userid="3" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:26:49.580" />
  <row id="3" userid="6" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row id="4" userid="15" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row id="5" userid="18" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row id="6" userid="21" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.197" />
  <row id="7" userid="27" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:46:49.213" />
  <row id="8" userid="7" name="Autobiographer" date="2010-08-25T19:51:49.327" />
</badges>

LOAD XML INFILE '/path/badges.xml' INTO TABLE meta ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';
```